# Prevent jQuery from creating duplicate clones via .clone() function

Tags: jquery, clone

I have the following code:

```
<div id="list-items">
  <ul class="item-list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Each time I click on this button it clone the `<ul> list`:

```
<div id="add">Add row</div>
```

It works with this JS code:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var newRow = $('.item-list').clone();
    $('#list-items').append(newRow);
});
```

Problem I have:
After several clicks on my button, it clones the entire  and not the part I want. An example can be found [here](http://code.runnable.com/VbOCxMy0Mwsnwf76/output).

How to prevent it ?

Comment: You are creating a clone of the whole list when you click on add, what you need is to get the first element and clone that

Comment: Ok perfect. Solved with `$('.item-list').eq(0).clone()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a clone of the whole list when you click on add, what you need is to get the first element and clone that
You should do something like this:

```
$( ".item-list" ).first().clone()
```